# Find index exists in elasticsearch 5.6

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i tried to check if an index exists or note before i do a search, i found a solution by performing requests, but it's not working, it results on a NullPointerException

```
@Autowired
private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

private List<E> convertToObjectList(SearchRequest searchRequest) {
    SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
    try {
        if (searchRequest != null) {
            RestClient restClient = null;
            Response response = restClient.performRequest("HEAD", "/" + index()); //java.lang.NullPointerException: null
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != 404) {
                searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error" + e);
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can definitely explain your `NullPointerException`:

```
        RestClient restClient = null;
        Response response = restClient.performRequest("HEAD", "/" + index());
```

Here you intitialize `restClient` with `null` and then call an operation on it.

It is the same as if you were calling ...

```
null.performRequest(...)
```

... which maybe makes the problem a bit more obvious.

You cannot call any operation (or get a field value or anything else) on a `null` value.